# Entity\Carousel::getArticleDestination(): Return value must be of type Entity\ArticleDestination, Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection returned

Tags: php, symfony, entity

In my code, I have a OneToOne relationship between 2 entity. When I try to create a new object from my back office, I have this error that i
I don't understand

*App\Entity\Carousel::getArticleDestination(): Return value must be of type App\Entity\ArticleDestination, Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection returned*

Here is my different entity.

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ArticleDestinationRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ArticleDestinationRepository::class)]
class ArticleDestination
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $name;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $mainland;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $country;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $intro;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $imageName;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'articleDestination', targetEntity: ArticleContent::class)]
    private $articleContent;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(inversedBy: 'articleDestination', targetEntity: Carousel::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    private $carousel;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'articleDestination', targetEntity: Hotel::class)]
    private $hotels;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'articleDestination', targetEntity: Food::class)]
    private $food;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->articleContent = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->hotels = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->food = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getMainland(): ?string
    {
        return $this->mainland;
    }

    public function setMainland(string $mainland): self
    {
        $this->mainland = $mainland;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCountry(): ?string
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    public function setCountry(string $country): self
    {
        $this->country = $country;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getIntro(): ?string
    {
        return $this->intro;
    }

    public function setIntro(string $intro): self
    {
        $this->intro = $intro;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getImageName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->imageName;
    }

    public function setImageName(string $imageName): self
    {
        $this->imageName = $imageName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, ArticleContent>
     */
    public function getArticleContent(): Collection
    {
        return $this->articleContent;
    }

    public function addArticleContent(ArticleContent $articleContent): self
    {
        if (!$this->articleContent->contains($articleContent)) {
            $this->articleContent[] = $articleContent;
            $articleContent->setArticleDestination($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeArticleContent(ArticleContent $articleContent): self
    {
        if ($this->articleContent->removeElement($articleContent)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($articleContent->getArticleDestination() === $this) {
                $articleContent->setArticleDestination(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCarousel(): ?Carousel
    {
        return $this->carousel;
    }

    public function setCarousel(?Carousel $carousel): self
    {
        $this->carousel = $carousel;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Hotel>
     */
    public function getHotels(): Collection
    {
        return $this->hotels;
    }

    public function addHotel(Hotel $hotel): self
    {
        if (!$this->hotels->contains($hotel)) {
            $this->hotels[] = $hotel;
            $hotel->setArticleDestination($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeHotel(Hotel $hotel): self
    {
        if ($this->hotels->removeElement($hotel)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($hotel->getArticleDestination() === $this) {
                $hotel->setArticleDestination(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, Food>
     */
    public function getFood(): Collection
    {
        return $this->food;
    }

    public function addFood(Food $food): self
    {
        if (!$this->food->contains($food)) {
            $this->food[] = $food;
            $food->setArticleDestination($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeFood(Food $food): self
    {
        if ($this->food->removeElement($food)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($food->getArticleDestination() === $this) {
                $food->setArticleDestination(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->getName();
    }
}
```

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Entity\ArticleDestination;
use App\Repository\CarouselRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: CarouselRepository::class)]
class Carousel
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'carousel', targetEntity: ImageCarousel::class)]
    private $imageCarousels;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(mappedBy: 'carousel', targetEntity: ArticleDestination::class, cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    private $articleDestination;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->articleDestination = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->imageCarousels = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, ImageCarousel>
     */
    public function getImageCarousels(): Collection
    {
        return $this->imageCarousels;
    }

    public function addImageCarousel(ImageCarousel $imageCarousel): self
    {
        if (!$this->imageCarousels->contains($imageCarousel)) {
            $this->imageCarousels[] = $imageCarousel;
            $imageCarousel->setCarousel($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeImageCarousel(ImageCarousel $imageCarousel): self
    {
        if ($this->imageCarousels->removeElement($imageCarousel)) {
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($imageCarousel->getCarousel() === $this) {
                $imageCarousel->setCarousel(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function getArticleDestination(): ?ArticleDestination
    {
        return $this->articleDestination;
    }

    public function setArticleDestination(?ArticleDestination $articleDestination): self
    {
        // unset the owning side of the relation if necessary
        if ($articleDestination === null && $this->articleDestination !== null) {
            $this->articleDestination->setCarousel(null);
        }

        // set the owning side of the relation if necessary
        if ($articleDestination !== null && $articleDestination->getCarousel() !== $this) {
            $articleDestination->setCarousel($this);
        }

        $this->articleDestination = $articleDestination;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
    
    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have set a return type of `?ArticleDestination` and you set `$this->articleDestination` to `$this->articleDestination = new ArrayCollection();`. so one of those is not correct. My guess is you need to remove it in the constructor (and it will be NULL to start with)

Comment: Ok thank you, I delete $this->articleDestination = new ArrayCollection(); and know it works well.